# Dividir datos de una tabla según un año

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo una practica de notas y tengo un problema.
El asunto es que en una tabla llamada Historial , almaceno las calificaciones de un estudiante de los 3 años de estudio. Es decir:
Notas de estudiante Juanito.

```
1 AÑO:   
LENGUAS 8.6  
CIENCIAS: 6.8  
MATEMATICA: 9.5  
SOCIALES: 6.6  

2 AÑO:  
LENGUAS 9.1  
CIENCIAS: 9.2  
MATEMATICA: 9.5  
SOCIALES: 7.5  

3 AÑO:  
LENGUAS 3.9  
CIENCIAS: 2.8  
MATEMATICA: 7.5  
SOCIALES: 6.9
```

En la base de datos yo almaceno la siguiente informacion:

```
id(int)  
materia(varchar)  
nombres(varchar)  
apellidos(varchar)  
nota(varchar)  
año(varchar)
```

En `id`(auto incremental)
En `materia` (Almaceno el nombre de la materia)
`nombres`(nombre..)
`apellidos`(apellidos..)
`nota`(notas..)
`año`(Aqui almaceno el año de la siguiente forma : 2018, 2019,2020) y asi sucesivamente).
Esta es la consulta que utilizo:

```
SELECT materia,nota,año, FROM historial WHERE nombres='juanito' ORDER BY año ASC
```

Cuando los muestro con un `While` todo bien, pero me gustaría que al mostrarlos sean por el año. Todo esta desarrollandose en PHP.

El resultado debería ser el siguiente:

```
2018      
LENGUAS 8.6   
CIENCIAS: 6.8   
MATEMATICA: 9.5   
SOCIALES: 6.6  

2019     
LENGUAS 9.1   
CIENCIAS: 9.2   
MATEMATICA: 9.5   
SOCIALES: 7.5    


2020  
LENGUAS 3.9   
CIENCIAS: 2.8   
MATEMATICA: 7.5   
SOCIALES: 6.9
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: agrega la consulta SQL que estas manejando

Comment: SELECT materia,nota,lectivo, FROM historial WHERE nombres='2juanito' ORDER BY lectivo ASC"

Comment: dale editar a tu pregunta y añade la consulta que estas manejando

Comment: ya lo he editado

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es hacerlo en `php`, cuando recorres el array de resultados guardas el año en una variable y sólo lo muestras cuando cambia.

Es mejor evitar el uso de caracteres especiales como "ñ" en el nombre de campos en la base de datos.

```
$ano = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {
   if ($ano != $result["ano"]) {
      echo $result["ano"]."<br>";
      $ano = $result["ano"]; //aqui almacenamos el nuevo valor para comparar los siguientes registros
   }
   echo $result["materia"].": ".$result["nota"]."<br>";
}
```

Con `mysql` un modo de hacerlo es seleccionando los años en la tabla y seleccionando cada asignatura mediante joins. Pongo un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE historial (
  ano INT,
  materia VARCHAR(50),
  nota VARCHAR(10),
  nombres VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2015,'LENGUAS','3.5','pepe');
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2015,'CIENCIAS','2.5','pepe');
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2016,'LENGUAS','3.5','pepe');
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2016,'CIENCIAS','2.5','pepe');
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2017,'LENGUAS','3.5','pepe');
INSERT INTO historial (ano,materia,nota,nombres) VALUES (2017,'CIENCIAS','2.5','pepe');

SELECT distinct H.ano, 
H1.materia AS materia1, H1.nota AS nota1,
H2.materia AS materia2, H2.nota AS nota2
FROM historial H
INNER JOIN historial H1 ON H1.ano=H.ano AND H1.materia='LENGUAS'
INNER JOIN historial H2 ON H2.ano=H.ano AND H2.materia='CIENCIAS'
AND H.nombres='pepe';
```

Este sería el resultado:

```
| ano  | materia1 | nota1 | materia2 | nota2 |
| ---- | -------- | ----- | -------- | ----- |
| 2015 | LENGUAS  | 3.5   | CIENCIAS | 2.5   |
| 2016 | LENGUAS  | 3.5   | CIENCIAS | 2.5   |
| 2017 | LENGUAS  | 3.5   | CIENCIAS | 2.5   |
```

---